# Formatting buttons for contentEditable reflect selection formatting

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

We have a `contenteditable="true"` div which we use as a wysiwyg text editor. We added a basic formatting toolbar similar to the one that uses Medium.com

[image]

Using `execCommand()`, we're able to make the selected text bold if, for instance, the user presses the `bold` button. This works great.

However, something we haven't managed to do yet is to make the `bold` button highlighted if the user selects a part of the text which is in bold, like illustrated in the picture above. This could be easily done by passing a `is-active` class on the button of course, but *how do we **know** that the selected text is, in this case, bold*?

We think it could perhaps be done using the `Selection` API but this use case seems undocumented.

Comment: share the fiddle or code piece mate

Answer (score 0):

since the execCommand() use html tag wrappers like B tag  **for bold** .
So when you are selecting the word i am sure you are using some sort of js to show that formating tollbar just add some more code in that function like this.

```
if(selectedElement.nodeName == "B"){
    toolbarBoldButton.classlist.add("is-active");
}
```

Note: i am using js function "nodeName" to get the tag name which was wrapped around the execCommand() in this case bold/B then matching if it matches the tag and if true i am adding the is-active class to the toolbars Bold style element.

Comment: @jivan also if you have that code on any git repo or anything let me know i will help you further with that if you like...